# Calling a variable from constructor in another method in java

Tags: java, methods, constructor

If I have a constructor that holds a variable. How can I call that variable in another method within the same class?

In my example below, I want the code to return false in the checkBoundaries method if the col is greater that the Columnnum that is in the constructor.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    class MovieSeating 
    {
        private String[][] Seats;

        public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
        {
            Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
            for (int r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
                {
                    Seats[r][c] = "?.?";
                    System.out.print(Seats[r][c] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }

            System.out.println("Seating is empty.");



        }

        public boolean checkBoundaries(int row, int col)
        {
            if (col < 0 || row < 0 || col >= columnNumInConstructorParameter)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mean a constructor with a parameter?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase in original.. sorry

Comment: The variable inside a constructor should be the instance or class variable. So that it can be accessed else where in the class. Do not declare a variable inside the constructor.

Comment: Your question is about scope of the variable. A method or a constructor are the same for scope of a variable. A method variable cannot be accessed from another method.

Comment: You can not "call" variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
if (col < 0 || row < 0 || col >= Seats[0].length)
```

In general, if you want to use a variable inside a method, it must be set as an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Make your variables into private instance members and call on them.

ex.

```
public class Foo {

    private int myVariable = 0;

    public Foo(int myVariable) {
        this.myVariable = myVariable;
    }

    public boolean positiveValue() {
        return this.myVariable > 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MovieSeating 
{
    private String[][] Seats;
    private int rowNumber = 0;
    private int columnNumber = 0;

    public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
    {
        this.rowNumber = rowNum;
        this.columnNumber = columnNum;
        Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
        for (int r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
            {
                Seats[r][c] = "?.?";
                System.out.print(Seats[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Seating is empty.");



    }

    public boolean checkBoundaries(int row, int col)
    {
        if (col < 0 || row < 0 || row >= rowNumber || col >= columnNumber)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it by parameters

```
public Classname(){
    String foo = "bar";        
    myMethod(foo);
}
public void myMethod(String parameter){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a better practice to keep constructor parameters into instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to store int rowNum, int columnNum as instance variable. However they are accessible from the size of the String[][] Seats variable

Consider adding something like:

```
private int getColumnNum() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException , NullPointerException{
    return Seats[0].length;
}
private int getRowNum(){
    return Seats.length;
}
```